# get description instead of an attribute name in impala query

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala, hue

While running

```
describe scheme1.table1
```

in Impala (using with Hue in Hadoop) as an output I am getting a table with columns

> 'name'
> 'type'
> 'comment'

In 'comment' field I see the detailed specification of the attribute values, while in 'name' field I see attribute id-codes.

Could you, please, say if it is possible to get in impala(or hive) query the 'comment' of the fields instead of 'name' of the fields?

For example, in normal life I write

```
select field1, field2 from scheme1.table1
```

The thing I want to do is a thing like

```
select comment(field1), comment(field2) from scheme1.table1
```

Comment: You should stick to `describe`, not `select`. If you want the comment as part of a select query, you need to query the Hive metastore where that data is actually available

Comment: Thank you, I realy want the comment as a part of a select query - I will try to do this task next week.